# How to log from a custom ai platform model

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

I recently deployed a custom model to google cloud's ai-platform, and I am trying to debug some parts of my preprocessing logic. However, My print statements are not being logged to the stackdriver output. I have also tried using the logging client imported from google.cloud, to no avail. Here is my custom prediction file:

```
import os
import pickle

import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import tensorflow as tf

from google.cloud import logging

class MyPredictor(object):
  def __init__(self, model, preprocessor):
    self.logging_client = logging.Client()
    self._model = model
    self._preprocessor = preprocessor
    self._class_names = ["Snare", "Kicks", "ClosedHH", "ClosedHH",  "Clap", "Crash", "Perc"]

  def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
    log_name = "Here I am"
    logger = self.logging_client.logger(log_name)
    text = 'Hello, world!'
    logger.log_text(text)
    print('Logged: {}'.format(text), kwargs.get("sr"))

    inputs = np.asarray(instances)

    outputs = self._model.predict(inputs)

    if kwargs.get('probabilities'):
      return outputs.tolist()
      #return "[]"
    else:
      return [self._class_names[index] for index in np.argmax(outputs.tolist(), axis=1)]

  @classmethod
  def from_path(cls, model_dir):
    model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'model.h5')
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects={"adam": tf.keras.optimizers.Adam, 
 "categorical_crossentropy":tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, "lr":0.01, "name": "Adam"})

    preprocessor_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'preprocessor.pkl')
    with open(preprocessor_path, 'rb') as f:
      preprocessor = pickle.load(f)

    return cls(model, preprocessor)
```

I can't find anything online for why my logs are not showing up in stackdriver (neither print statements nor the logging library calls). Has anyone faced this issue?

Thanks,
Nikita

NOTE: If you have enough rep to create tags please add the google-ai-platform tag to this post. I think it would really help people who are in my position. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nikita, I found the same issue, will get back to you with findings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-predict#requesting_logs_for_online_prediction_requests):

> If you want to enable online prediction logging, you must configure it
>   when you create a model resource or when you create a model version
>   resource, depending on which type of logging you want to enable. There
>   are three types of logging, which you can enable independently:
>
> Access logging, which logs information like timestamp and latency for
>   each request to Stackdriver Logging.
>
> You can enable access logging when you create a model resource.
>
> Stream logging, which logs the stderr and stdout streams from your
>   prediction nodes to Stackdriver Logging, and can be useful for
>   debugging. This type of logging is in beta, and it is not supported by
>   Compute Engine (N1) machine types.
>
> You can enable stream logging when you create a model resource.
>
> Request-response logging, which logs a sample of online prediction
>   requests and responses to a BigQuery table. This type of logging is in
>   beta.
>
> You can enable request-response logging by creating a model version
>   resource, then updating that version.

For your use case, please use the following template to log custom information into StackDriver:

**Model**

```
gcloud beta ai-platform models create {MODEL_NAME} \
 --regions {REGION} \
 --enable-logging \
 --enable-console-logging
```

**Model version**

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {VERSION_NAME} \
    --model {MODEL_NAME} \
    --origin gs://{BUCKET}/{MODEL_DIR} \
    --python-version 3.7 \
    --runtime-version 1.15 \
    --package-uris gs://{BUCKET}/{PACKAGES_DIR}/custom-model-0.1.tar.gz \
    --prediction-class=custom_prediction.CustomModelPrediction \
    --service-account custom@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I tried this and worked fine:

- I did some modification to the constructor due to the @classmethod decorator.
- Create a service account and grant it "Stackdriver Debugger User" role, use it during model version creation
- Add `google-cloud-logging` library to your `setup.py`
- Consider extra cost of enabling StackDriver logging
- When using `log_struct` check the correct type is passed. (If using `str`, make sure you convert `bytes` to `str` in Python 3 using `.decode('utf-8')`)
- Define the project_id parameter during Stackdriver client creation 
  `logging.Client()`, otherwise you will get:

```
ERROR:root:Prediction failed: 400 Name "projects//logs/my-custom-prediction-log" is missing the parent component. Expected the form projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/[ID]"
```

Code below:

```
%%writefile cloud_logging.py

import os
import pickle
import numpy as np

from datetime import date
from google.cloud import logging

import tensorflow.keras as keras
LOG_NAME = 'my-custom-prediction-log'

class CustomModelPrediction(object):
    def __init__(self, model, processor, client):    
        self._model = model
        self._processor = processor
        self._client = client

    def _postprocess(self, predictions):
        labels = ['negative', 'positive']
        return [
            {
                "label":labels[int(np.round(prediction))],
                "score":float(np.round(prediction, 4))
            } for prediction in predictions]

    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
        logger = self._client.logger(LOG_NAME)
        logger.log_struct({'instances':instances})
        preprocessed_data = self._processor.transform(instances)
        predictions =  self._model.predict(preprocessed_data)
        labels = self._postprocess(predictions)
        return labels

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):        
        client = logging.Client(project='project_id') # Change to your project
        model = keras.models.load_model(
          os.path.join(model_dir,'keras_saved_model.h5'))
        with open(os.path.join(model_dir, 'processor_state.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
            processor = pickle.load(f)    
        return cls(model, processor, client)

# Verify model locally

from cloud_logging import CustomModelPrediction
classifier = CustomModelPrediction.from_path('.')

requests = ["God I hate the north", "god I love this"]
response = classifier.predict(requests)
response
```

Then I check with the [sample library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/logging/cloud-client):

```
python snippets.py my-custom-prediction-log list
Listing entries for logger my-custom-prediction-log:
* 2020-02-19T19:51:45.809767+00:00: {u'instances': [u'God I hate the north', u'god I love this']}
* 2020-02-19T19:57:18.615159+00:00: {u'instances': [u'God I hate the north', u'god I love this']}
```

To visualize the logs, in StackDriver > Logging > Select Global and your Log name, if you want to see Model logs you should be able to select Cloud ML Model version.

You can use my files here: [model](https://storage.googleapis.com/news-ml-experiments/processor_state.pkl) and [pre-processor](https://storage.googleapis.com/news-ml-experiments/processor_state.pkl)

Comment: the `model` and `pre-processor` links are identical

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your print to work and not use the logging method above me you can just add flush flag to your print,

```
print(“logged”,flush=True)
```