# Writing simple logs to cloud bucket with google ai-platform request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

In GCP ai-platform I am trying to write simple logs to a file in addition to saving a tf.keras model. However, saving the model with `tf.saved_model.save` works, while writing to a .txt using `with open(file) as out:` does not and raises this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://my-test-bucket-001/keras-job-dir/mnist_model_export/results.txt'
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference in how ai-platform discovers file paths?

My request essentially looks like this (see https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-keras)

```
...
JOB_DIR = gs://my-test-bucket-001/keras-job-dir
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \ 
 --package-path trainer/  \
 --module-name trainer.task  \
 --region $REGION  \
 --python-version 3.7  \
 --runtime-version 2.1  \
 --job-dir $JOB_DIR  \
 --stream-logs
```

The relevant part of trainer/task.py script is this:

```
   # use this path to save outputs
   export_path = os.path.join(args.job_dir, 'mnist_model_export')
   # this works
   tf.saved_model.save(mnist_model, export_path)

   # this fails when included
   with open(os.path.join(export_path, 'results.txt'), 'a+') as out:
      log_str = "Job finished! {}\n".format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
      out.write(log_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `with open(os.path.join(export_path, 'results.txt'), 'a+') as out:`
you are using the **local** file system and since you pass in `export_path` a `gs://` path, it returns file does not exists, since the `gs://` path is not available locally. You need to use a file handler that supports reading/writing into GCS buckets. For example [FileIO](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py#L37)

Replace:

```
 with open(os.path.join(export_path, 'results.txt'), 'a+') as out:
      log_str = "Job finished! {}\n".format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
      out.write(log_str)
```

With:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
with file_io.FileIO(os.path.join(export_path, 'results.txt'), mode='a+') as out:
      log_str = "Job finished! {}\n".format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
      out.write(log_str)
```

You may want to check out other Logging options [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60163113/how-to-log-from-a-custom-ai-platform-model/60308285#60308285).

Comment: thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't help in my case.

ERROR 2020-03-13 17:59:42 -0400 service  tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 404 with body '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: my-test-bucket/keras-job-dir/mnist_model_export/results.txt</Details></Error>'

Comment: basic question, are you passing: gs://my-test-bucket/keras-job-dir/mnist_model_export/results.txt or my-test-bucket/keras-job-dir/mnist_model_export/results.txt  as filename?

Comment: I do have 'gs://' in front, but the parser ignores it when outputs an error message. So, the result of print below is 'gs://my-test-bucket/keras-job-dir/v2w_var_....', and then writing fails with same error.

`export_path = os.path.join(args.job_dir, 'v2w_var_{}'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')))`

>>>`tf.saved_model.save(mod_var, export_path)`

>>>`print(export_path)`

>>>`with file_io.FileIO(os.path.join(export_path, 'results.txt'), mode='a+') as out:`

>>>`log_str = "Job finished! {}\n".format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

>>>`out.write(log_str)`

Thank you!

Comment: Are you still stuck on this problem? I can try to repro tomorrow

Comment: Thx for getting back! I ended up only saving a model with `tf.save` . I am still interested in knowing the solution